# Does my token approval for trading on Uniswap expire after a certain time?

Tags: tokens, uniswap, trading

I'm doing some trades on Uniswap and I approved token trading on one of the tokens. But I'm getting another approval request. Do these approvals expire after a certain time? It doesnt make sense to pay the fee again just to do an approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approval do **not** expire after a certain time.

If you already approved an **unlimited** amount of that token with that same address, then Uniswap should not ask you to approve it again. If it does, there are two possibilities:

1. It is not the same token (watch out for scam tokens that have the same name);
2. You are not using the same address as the one you did the approval with (check which address is connected).
3. Your previous approval was for a different contract. For instance, you approved for Uniswap V2 and you now want to swap on V3 (your case). Or, you are on a phishing website that pretends to be uniswap and asks for approval to a scam contract.

Comment: I figured out what happened. Looks like approval was for V3 of uniswap. When I first did the approval it was for V2. But at least now I'll be aware if it asks for multiple approvals and that it doesnt expire.

Comment: So it looks like there is a third possibility - the contract itself is different (`spender` in the ERC-20 standard). @Undead8 you should edit the answer.

Comment: I'm constantly being asked for approvals for already approved tokens. Same contract, same pool, same version (v2).